# Problem in executing a built jar file in netbeans

Tags: java, jar, netbeans6.7

I've just made a game in netbeans. The Problem is that after builting the game. I'm not able to execute the jar file and getting the exception:
**Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
Game.jar**

What to do???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a JAR to be self-executable, you have to include the `Main-Class` line in a manifest.

I'm not a NetBeans user, but this is how it's done.

Create a `manifest.mf` file:

```
Main-Class: YourGame
<newline>
```

Build the jar:
`jar cmf manifest.mf Game.jar path/to/classes/*.class`

You should now be able to to double-click on the JAR to run it (assuming Windows), or you can run it via the command line:

`java -jar Game.jar`

Of course, you can always run from the command line without the need for a manifest:

`java -cp .;Game.jar YourGame`

Comment: Good explanation! I'd just like to emphasize that 'YourGame' is the fully qualified classname, iaw most likely `my.pckg.containing.YourGame` or so. And if the game depends on other libraries, you can not use the `-cp` parameter in conjunction with `-jar` - it's almost always better to start the app with Matt's second suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The Main-Class attribute needs a new line after it in order to be parsed correctly.

Show your `manifest.mf`,

Answer (score 1):

Edit manifest file as proposed by others, or in NetBeans just right-click the project (in sidebar), select *Properties*, category *Run* and hit *Browse...* next to *Main Class*.